# Add and print multiple char in C

Tags: c, char, int, addition, scanf

I'm creating a Dice Game, where the user rolls 3 dice and gets some random outputs (up to integer 6). My next step is to add those 3 values obtained and get its sum. 
How do I achieve this? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Here's my source code:

```
//Roll-a-dice Game!
int main(){
    char input1;
    char input2;
    char input3;
    int i;
    int diceRoll;
    int sumDice = (int)(input1-'0') + (int)(input2-'0') + (int)(input3-'0');

    printf("User's First Input: (Press any key to continue) ");
    scanf("\n %c", &input1);

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        diceRoll = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("%d\n\n", diceRoll);
    }

    printf("User's Second Input: (Press any key to continue) ");
    scanf("\n %c", &input2);

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        diceRoll = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("%d\n\n", diceRoll);
    }

    printf("User's Third Input: (Press any key to continue) ");
    scanf("\n %c", &input3);

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        diceRoll = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("%d\n\n", diceRoll);
    }


    printf("Sum of observations: %d", sumDice);

    return 0;
}
```

The ***sumDice*** function doesn't output the correct answer and I think the problem lies somewhere in this particular function.

Comment: You need to calculate `sumDice` *after* you've rolled the dice, not before.

Comment: You're calculating `sumDice` before you've done any input to the variables. How do you expect to sum them before you've gotten them? This is plain common sense: you can't count the money in your wallet before you've put money in your wallet in the first place. This is what happens when you write code without even bothering to read what you've written (or copy/paste code from others without understanding what it does).

Comment: why are you summing the chars?

Comment: @KenWhite Firstly, I apologize for my unfortunate mistake, the probable reason for which was my lack of concentration or common sense. I regret not looking back at my code before posting. It was just a matter of a small cut/paste error I had while debugging the code.

Comment: Don't edit the question to incorporate the answer; by doing so you make all of the answers invalid.

Comment: @wolfPack88 I didn't know that, sorry (it's my first post here). Thanks for pointing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by this statment:

> where the user rolls 3 dice and gets some random outputs (up to
>   integer 6). My next step is to add those 3 values obtained and get its
>   sum

I assume you want this:

first initialize `sumDice` to `0`:

```
int sumDice=0;
```

then, in every for loop add this after `diceRoll=rand()...` line:

```
sumDice+=diceRoll;
```

and remove the last `sumDice= (int)(input-'0')...` line.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind `int sumDice = (int)(input1-'0') + (int)(input2-'0') + (int)(input3-'0');` makes sense, but you must use it after assigning values to `input1`, `input2` and `input3`.

You are getting the wrong answer because when you initialize `sumDice` at the beginning, the input variables are not initialized, so they have random values stored in them.

Here is where you must put it :

```
int sumDice = (int)(input1-'0') + (int)(input2-'0') + (int)(input3-'0');
printf("Sum of observations: %d", sumDice);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done the changes to my code.
By the way, I'd done it the way you've described the first time after which I did some changes to my code. Sorry, that I did not look back at my code before posting. My bad.

Comment: @Adivir Feel free to accept my post as the original answer if your problem has been solved.

Comment: I still wasn't getting the correct answer, until @Jahid pointed out the errors. The code works fine now. Thanks for your help by the way, I really appreciate it.